# Converting a big string in R to hex

Tags: r, boolean, hex

I need to convert a big string of 1M booleans to hexadecimal. I can't figure the right library or syntax. I thought I could use a gsub after I converted the booleans to char, but I can't keep it in raw data type. Each FALSE needs to be a 0x0 and TRUE needs to be a 0x8. So, this :

> FALSEFALSEFALSETRUEFALSEFALSE

becomes this raw data:

> 000800

Here's a snip of code I've been playing with:

```
sample<-paste0(sample(x=c(T,F),size=100,replace=T),collapse="")
best_raw<-as.vector(sample) %>%
    as.character(.) %>%
    paste(.,collapse="") %>%
    gsub(x=.,pattern="TRUETRUE",replacement=as.raw(0x88)) %>%
    gsub(x=.,pattern="FALSEFALSE",replacement=as.raw(0x00)) %>%
    gsub(x=.,pattern="TRUEFALSE",replacement=as.raw(0x80)) %>%
    gsub(x=.,pattern="FALSETRUE",replacement=as.raw(0x08))
```

but a few things become obvious... first, I thought I was cleverly using characters and as.raw by taking two booleans at a time, but gsub does not respect the pairs going in so I get a mash of stuff like:

> "8088TRUE00TRUE000000880800888088TRUE"

I've seen a few references to bin2hex, but I can't find it in CRAN and I'm not sure it would do what I want anyway.

Comment: Could you clarify what the inputs and outputs are? In your code the sample input is of type character, not raw, is that the case of the actual data? And I don't think R has a proper hexadecimal type, so you want the output to be integers with 0 for FALSE and 8 for TRUE? Or you want it as a character string?

Comment: Why is `TRUE` equal to `0x8`?

Comment: @Alexlok, my input is a boolean vector. I've amended the sample by changing the "TRUE" to T and "FALSE" to F.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, unfortunately, my code is being inserted in a legacy flow, and for some reason F is 0b0000 and T is 0b1000 or 1000[2]. I think it's easier to notate that with 0x0 and 0x8.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what type of data are your inputs and outputs. In the legacy script, what happens if you run `typeof()` on the input and output?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you have a character string with TRUE and FALSE concatenated. You can directly use `gsub` to replace them with numbers. Then you can separate the individual numbers to get a vector rather than a single long string and you can apply the conversion you need on that final vector.

```
smp <- paste0(sample(x=c("TRUE","FALSE"),size=100,replace=T),collapse="")
smp_as_numbers <- gsub("FALSE", "0",gsub("TRUE", "8", smp, fixed=TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
smp_as_vector <- strsplit(smp_as_numbers, "")[[1]]
as.raw(as.integer(smp_as_vector))

> as.raw(as.integer(smp_as_vector))
#  [1] 08 00 00 00 00 08 00 08 08 08 08 08 08 00 08 08 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 08 08 08
# [29] 08 00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 08 08 00 00 00 00 08 08 08 08 08 08 00 08 00 08 08 00
# [57] 00 08 08 00 08 00 08 08 08 00 08 08 08 08 00 08 08 00 00 00 08 00 08 08 08 00 08 08
# [85] 08 00 08 00 00 08 08 00 00 08 08 00 00 08 00 00
> smp
#[1] #"TRUEFALSEFALSEFALSEFALSETRUEFALSETRUETRUETRUETRUETRUETRUEFALSETRUETRUEFALSETRUEFALSEFALSEFALSEFALSEFALSETRUEFALSETRUETRUETRUETRUEFALSEFALSETRUEFALSEFALSEFALSETRUEFALSEFALSETRUETRUEFALSEFALSEFALSEFALSETRUETRUETRUETRUETRUETRUEFALSETRUEFALSETRUETRUEFALSEFALSETRUETRUEFALSETRUEFALSETRUETRUETRUEFALSETRUETRUETRUETRUEFALSETRUETRUEFALSEFALSEFALSETRUEFALSETRUETRUETRUEFALSETRUETRUETRUEFALSETRUEFALSEFALSETRUETRUEFALSEFALSETRUETRUEFALSEFALSETRUEFALSEFALSE"
```

If you want to use `BMS::hex2bin()`, you have to use directly the non-split characters:

```
smp <- paste0(sample(x=c("TRUE","FALSE"),size=5,replace=T),collapse="")
smp_as_numbers <- gsub("FALSE", "0",gsub("TRUE", "8", smp, fixed=TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
smp_as_numbers
# [1] "08888"
BMS::hex2bin(smp_as_numbers)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

typeof(BMS::hex2bin(smp_as_numbers))
# [1] "double"
```

Comment: I think you understand very closely. The last step is something that i'm struggling with. Instead of returning 8 bit values (0x08 and 0x00), I need to return 4 bit values (0x0 and 0x8). I don't think as.raw likes that...

Comment: The package BMS has the function `hex2bin()` you mention that can do that. I'm adding a second example.